# Integrate CKEditor 4 in EXT JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, ckeditor, integration

Thank you in advance. 
I'm trying to integrate CKEditor 4 with my extjs 4.2 project. 
Can someone help me with the integration please ?
After searching web I found [This example](http://www.programering.com/a/MzNzQjMwATY.html), but it wasn't working as "this.editor" was undefined. 
Also I tried using "CKEDITOR.instances[this.id]" but still no help. This raised another error "Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined". 
That would be really appreciable if someone could help me out.

Comment: Please provide the code you already tried, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy new. Found the solution.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.CKEditor', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
alias: 'widget.ckeditor',

constructor: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.addEvents("instanceReady");
    this.addEvents("blur");
},

initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.on("afterrender", function () {
        Ext.apply(this.CKConfig, {
            height: this.getHeight(),
            width: this.getWidth()
        });

        this.editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this.inputEl.id, this.CKConfig);
        this.editor.name = this.name;

        this.editor.on("instanceReady", function () {
            this.fireEvent("instanceReady", this, this.editor );
        }, this);

        this.editor.on("blur", function (){
            this.fireEvent("blur", this, this.editor );
        }, this)

    }, this);
},

onRender: function (ct, position) {
    if (!this.el) {
        this.defaultAutoCreate = {
            tag: 'textarea',
            autocomplete: 'off'
        };
    }
    this.callParent(arguments)
},

setValue: function (value) {    
    this.callParent(arguments);
    if (this.editor) {
        this.editor.setData(value);
    }
},

getValue: function () {
    if (this.editor) {
        console.log(this.editor.getData());
        return this.editor.getData();
    } 
    else {
        return ''
    }
}
```

});

This integrates the ckeditor with EXT jS.